# Get access token AZURE ad B2C user

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-authentication

I have the following requirement:

1. create a user on AD B2C.
2. using the credentials of that user, I need to get access token and refresh token to access an existing api(REST SERVICE).

Active directory here is Azure AD.

I am new in oAuth and Azure. Please suggest me the steps and configuration to achieve this. (I do not want any user interaction to get access token and refresh token).
creating a user is clear to me. but if it requires any specific type of user or any required permissions, please suggest those.

Comment: Are you sure you need a user account here and not a service principal?

Comment: I need to create user because application is multi tenant, if a service principal can be created per tenant, I am ok with that also(but creating user will be more helpful). @MartinBrandl

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds like your use case can be **better realized with a service principal**. If you don't need a user context but, consider using an SP instead. See:
[Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)

If for whatever reason you want to stick to non-interactive user login, you can use the [Resource Owner Password Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203). But be aware that:

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios,
> more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow
> requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries
> risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this
> flow when other more secure flows can't be used.